# PDF presentation, storing multiple proportions

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf

I've prepared a presentation in InDesign, that's supposed to be seen on very different screens. I'd like this presentation to look the best, despite the proportions of screen that it's beeing seen on.

So, in my example, two screens: 4:3 and 16:9. Is there a way to prepare a smart scalable PDF file, that would fit to full screen?

Comment: That is beyond the intended purpose of the PDF file format. Make 2 PDFs.

Comment: @Jongware That short comment should be an answer. It's probably the best (and only) solution in that situation!

Comment: Yeah  i was suspecting that, too bad. Thanks for help!